# How to set the dynamic value from a text box to the graph using Highcharts?

Tags: jquery, laravel, highcharts

I am trying to populate the graph which is drawn using Highcharts, with the dynamic value from text box.
Below is my code for the chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pendingSSC = $("#pendingSSC").val();
    var pendingAgency = $("#pendingAgency").val();
    Highcharts.chart('container',{
        chart:{
            type: 'column'
        },
        title:{
            text: 'Pivot Table'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Pivot data']
        },
        yAxis:{
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series:[
            {
                name:'Pending-SSC',
                data:[pendingSSC],
                stack:'pending'
            },
            {
                name:'Pending-Agency',
                data:[pendingAgency],
                stack:'pending'
            }

        ]
    });
</script>
```

I have to draw this chart on success of an ajax function.

The chart accepts a static value. For some reason it does not accept the dynamic values.

The values are empty.

Comment: could you provide the function of AJAX call ,i think you need to use promise:wait for ajax request to return data ,then populate the chart

Comment: My graph is present in a div which is hidden, on ajax success this div is shown. Am I making a mistake in this????

Comment: @Thilagam note highcharts accepts number in data array so use `var pendingSSC =Number($("#pendingSSC").val())`

Comment: @Patata Thank you. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series#1) accepts number in data array so update

```
var pendingSSC =Number($("#pendingSSC").val())
var pendingAgency = Number($("#pendingAgency").val());
```